# Do you need premium to change your gun camo?

Tags: battlefield-3

I do not have a premium account but I wish to be able to change my gun camo.
Do I need to be a premium player or is it just a matter of rank before I can change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Camouflage skins for your weapons are only available for Premium Players of Battlefield 3.

Only the premium package in Battlelog contains assignments that can be completed for skins. The DLC's only contain new weapons to unlock.

[image]